# Prevent users from selecting same value in multiple dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

I am loading a table from an API call , table rows are dynamic and it is based on the returned values from API call. I am displaying sort order and value should be unique and user shouldn't select a previously selected values. I tried to follow as per this (http://jsfiddle.net/jnash21/oqezom4y/) but i am not able to achieve as mine is dynamic.

I tried this (http://embed.plnkr.co/QU4r05n9rQprwyL9Ltxh/) .

```
editor.controller('EditorController', function($scope) {

  $scope.entities = [{name:"pencil",sortOrder:""} ,{name:"notepad",sortOrder:""} ,
  {name:"bookshelf",sortOrder:""}
  ];

  $scope.sortOrderValues=[1,2,3];
});

    <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in entities">
    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
    <td><select ng-model="x.sortOrder"
                ng-options="col for col in sortOrderValues"> 
       </select>
          <span ng-show="!x.sortOrder"> * sort order required</span>  
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I prevent a user from selecting same sort order in each row using angular js?

Comment: The best solution I can think of is to put a copy of that sortOrderValues list onto each of the entities being displayed in the table.  Then, I think you'll have to loop through those entities every time a value is changed in one of those dropdowns and update each dropdown to have the correct options.

Comment: You can just have a master set that controls selected. Then when you select one you add that value to the set. Change the NG options to an NG repeat and add a NG disable based on the value being in the set.  You can ngif based on whether you want to hide or disable the options. Users choice I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LKv4nQCwMRI6P9FT7MjX?p=preview) might help you.

First of all, genereate an array from 1 to `entities.length` (this case, 3).
When you select an option, tirgger the `optionSelected` function. This function will generate your inital array and calculate the used `sortOrders` by your `entities`. Then it filters the second ones from the first array.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="EditorController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in entities">
      <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
      <td><select ng-model="x.sortOrder"
                  ng-options="col for col in sortOrderValues"
                  ng-change="optionSelected()"> 
         </select>
            <span ng-show="!x.sortOrder"> * sort order required</span>  
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
editor.controller('EditorController', function($scope) {

  $scope.entities = [{name:"pencil",sortOrder:""} ,{name:"notepad",sortOrder:""} ,
  {name:"bookshelf",sortOrder:""}
  ];

  // Genereate all the numbers between 1 and $scope.entities.length
  $scope.sortOrderValues= $scope.entities.map(
    function (item, index) {
      return index + 1;
    }
  );

  // Function executed when you select a sortOrder
  $scope.optionSelected = function () {
    // Genereate all the numbers between 1 and $scope.entities.length
    var allIndexes = $scope.entities
      .map(function (entity, index) { return index + 1; });

    // Get all the sortOrder used
    var usedIndexes = $scope.entities
      .map(function(e) { return e.sortOrder; });

    // Remove from the [1, .., $scope.entities.length] array all the sortOrder used
    $scope.sortOrderValues = allIndexes
      .filter(function (order) {
        return !usedIndexes.find(function(index) { return index === order; });
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , once value is selected , it is removed from list , and selected value disappears , this is not the expected outcome .

Comment: So you want leave already selected values on the list, but not be abke to select them?

Comment: Yes , i managed achieve , will post it here. thanks for your help